# Connecting Shibboleth as a IdP and API Publisher as SP

Tags: wso2, shibboleth, wso2-identity-server

### The Plan

We went to configure shibboleth as the IdP so we can do SSO. We have shibboleth configured already for the many other things we do like email and account information, but when trying to add in our API publisher to the mix we seem to be getting an error. We believe it to be a wso2 configuration error. We been using this wso2 documentation as a template: *How to Configure Shibboleth IdP as a Trusted Identity Provider*

### The Situation

So far we are able to get to the login screen and put in our credentials, but when it tries to redirect us we get a Error 401 : Authorization Required.

### SAML code

```
<saml2p:Response 
Destination="localhost" 
ID="mbnfmmagbmefckldpefbmjopkadjahbkocadhmib" 
InResponseTo="lihfmcpiofkdkhphfbahlndllmmemhldckammgaf" 
IssueInstant="2016-12-05T16:20:37.939Z" 
Version="2.0" 
xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<saml2:Issuer 
    Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity" 
    xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">IdsDev
</saml2:Issuer>
<ds:Signature 
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod 
            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod 
            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference 
            URI="#mbnfmmagbmefckldpefbmjopkadjahbkocadhmib">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform 
                    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                <ds:Transform 
                    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces 
                        PrefixList="xs" 
                        xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod 
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>9xbWKA7A+
                7k7Vaz6O18z8Xliqbo=
            </ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>kX11Q4eCUyME+VP5M7+5iI6D45kqQgE6MIqth7hNosSmfdSD3kZS0dwlcNwVlrzA64LMUZxclU256xP6w6nn0TqEqLjKy/tGXeQbKjaYrPcXx6336kIp8YGajqDiBh7IJswFDxugLoRx70APaKGthJi5VwRea1oT3lE4RHJoMgiN7o5FO1N+8IE34zEJLmTIpt+lYdXQPJanN29GY9YfIouFe2TGfHfXd9PT2nt7Dmf+M69DM3giEyizbzljYHdkjJrTlqoYTlHBHNPq8NF/+1wwuL76SP0Bory4k/7JvelW6RSAz82pdjDc0ublBmuceTENza2GiC2sitVQPycl/
        g==
    </ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>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
                OvSamgXd5RBJbXq376LX3r9jcYGpQwJT3hqMl9Qa1B0pY=
            </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<saml2p:Status>
    <saml2p:StatusCode 
        Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
</saml2p:Status>
<saml2:Assertion 
    ID="gihomiibdbpcojhdmjofkecelaibhdcdonghhkpm" 
    IssueInstant="2016-12-05T16:20:37.939Z" 
    Version="2.0" 
    xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <saml2:Issuer 
        Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">IdsDev
    </saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature 
        xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod 
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod 
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <ds:Reference 
                URI="#gihomiibdbpcojhdmjofkecelaibhdcdonghhkpm">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform 
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <ds:Transform 
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces 
                            PrefixList="xs" 
                            xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod 
                    Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>Z7DIvjwTk4JpF0TRMNzo3Z/
                    4sfc=
                </ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>h1Stjkbw306VU7TN5OEou2XII3nzvhr34GVbced5Gk7q+EZailZusYISkC11eJjk4Y+CejMa4RODelwnMAdpfeWmMYz6ukk0jh9RH97/uWPOWKfOp4n/oXVnYE3rdImGcb1egas/zprqM7Pl8mbwI7vK3ScMUagBg6Td1sxHfRgVBk6r8C+40sgTAG8LsOd+q8LKNYj5mSeZ5K34SBdkmMWNpAS9mOT9CSJfWOrd9uAvFXHeuWN31MbIgVV5seEMfUzC18I/4s3qXwWqIvQxIsF8l9WuIuMYsFPT+oQJBU/ltQVf54w29k50tvN+LyvmNbZCZANf+
            3JXwygyImc2Yg==
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>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
                    OvSamgXd5RBJbXq376LX3r9jcYGpQwJT3hqMl9Qa1B0pY=
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:NameID 
            Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">username
        </saml2:NameID>
        <saml2:SubjectConfirmation 
            Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData 
                InResponseTo="lihfmcpiofkdkhphfbahlndllmmemhldckammgaf" 
                NotOnOrAfter="2016-12-05T16:25:37.939Z" 
                Recipient="localhost"/>
        </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml2:Subject>
    <saml2:Conditions 
        NotBefore="2016-12-05T16:20:37.939Z" 
        NotOnOrAfter="2016-12-05T16:25:37.939Z">
        <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
            <saml2:Audience>API_PUBLISHER</saml2:Audience>
        </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
    </saml2:Conditions>
    <saml2:AuthnStatement 
        AuthnInstant="2016-12-05T16:20:37.941Z" 
        SessionIndex="cbc00514-954b-4de2-8e7b-b50edf9c5976">
        <saml2:AuthnContext>
            <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
        </saml2:AuthnContext>
    </saml2:AuthnStatement>
    <saml2:AttributeStatement>
        <saml2:Attribute 
            Name="http://wso2.org/claims/fullname" 
            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml2:AttributeValue 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:type="xs:string">username
            </saml2:AttributeValue>
        </saml2:Attribute>
    </saml2:AttributeStatement>
</saml2:Assertion>
```

### IdP Config

[Shibboleth IDS configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXQL4.png)

[Shibboleth IDS configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUsjs.png)

Comment: Does the 401 Error occurs on the Shobboleth or WSO2IS server? Could you switch to the DEBUG level and see what's in the logs (wso2carbon.log)?  (I believe it's not the cause, but at least make the signatures consistent, ticket is using sha1 digent and rsa-sha1 signature, your screenshots are stating otherwise)

Comment: @GabrielVince Thanks for the comment. It looks like it's on the WSO2IS server. When I go check the wso2carbon.log nothing shows up, no errors or anything. So far we think that the cause may be the name ID we get from shibboleth. Shibboleth is only sending the username back but the IS server needs the nameID back as _domain name_ / _username_ to see that the user is authorized. Or so far is are best guess.

Comment: Looking through yesterdays logs I found this:

[2016-12-05 14:44:45,100] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.manager.DefaultSAML2SSOManager} -  Error while populating SAMLRequest wit
h AttributeConsumingServiceIndex: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"

not sure if it really concerns are current problem though.

Comment: Found a documentation and a blog post regarding this question. See if they help to solve your problem. 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/How+To%3A+Configure+Shibboleth+IdP+as+a+Trusted+Identity+Provider
http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/12/04/federatation-shibboleth/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved the problem! So we couldn't get shibboleth 2 to send the right information in the subject/nameID in the SAML code, but when we tried shibboleth 3 the customization of the nameID was an easier thing to work with. Anyways, wso2 could not authorize access with just the username in the subject/nameID, it also needed the domain and formated like this *domain*/*username*. With that we got SSO to work.